# Git log (or rev-list) but only show commits that are in every path for a given range

Tags: git

Is there a way to only display the commits via `git log` or `git rev-list` that are common to every path within a given range? E.g. for the commit graph and the given range from A to AB2, only display AB2, AB, and A.

```
* AB2
* AB
|\
| * B2
| * B
* | A2
|/
* A
```

Using `git log --merges ...` is almost what I need, but even merge commits may not be on every path.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. You can always read the entire graph (`git log --parents` or `git rev-list --parents`) in a program that you write yourself that picks out the interesting commits, and then spit those hash IDs into a second `git log --stdin`. Writing the selection program won't be trivial, though.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the Commit History
Some advanced methods for selecting specific commits in the project history are as follows:

By Amount : `git log -3`

By Date :  `git log --after="2014-7-1"`
`git log --after="2014-7-1" --before="2014-7-4"`
`git log --after="yesterday"`

By Author : `git log --author="John"` `git log --author="John\|Mary"`

By Message : `git log --grep="JRA-224:"`

By File : `git log -- foo.py bar.py`

By Content : `git log -S"Hello, World!"`

By Range : `git log --`

git log `main..feature`

You can read the full article in the link below

[https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log#:~:text=The%20most%20basic%20filtering%20option,output%20by%20including%20the%20%2D%20option](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log#:%7E:text=The%20most%20basic%20filtering%20option,output%20by%20including%20the%20%2D%20option).

Comment: None of these alternatives answer the OP's question.